# ipcluster on Sun Grid Engine has only ranks 0

Tags: python, ipython, sungridengine, ipython-parallel

I set up an IPython parallel `ipcluster` to use the Sun Grid Engine and things seem to work fine:

`ipcluster start -n 100 --profile=sge`

```
2016-07-15 14:47:09.749 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2016-07-15 14:47:09.751 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /home/USERNAME/.ipython/profile_sge/pid/ipcluster.pid
2016-07-15 14:47:09.751 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with SGEControllerLauncher
2016-07-15 14:47:09.789 [IPClusterStart] Job submitted with job id: u'6354583'
2016-07-15 14:47:10.790 [IPClusterStart] Starting 100 Engines with SGEEngineSetLauncher
2016-07-15 14:47:10.826 [IPClusterStart] Job submitted with job id: u'6354584'
2016-07-15 14:47:40.856 [IPClusterStart] Engines appear to have started successfully
```

Then I connect from the notebook using

`rc = ipp.Client(profile='sge')`

but when I use the parallel magic

```py
%%px
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
nprocs = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

print('I am #{} of {} and run on {}'.format(rank,nprocs,MPI.Get_processor_name()))
```

I all the processes return only `rank 0`:

```
[stdout:0] I am #0 of 1 and run on compute-8-13.local
[stdout:1] I am #0 of 1 and run on compute-8-13.local
[stdout:2] I am #0 of 1 and run on compute-3-3.local
[stdout:3] I am #0 of 1 and run on compute-3-3.local
[stdout:4] I am #0 of 1 and run on compute-3-3.local
...
```

Here are my setup scripts:

---

- `ipcluster_config.py`:

  ```
  c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SGEEngineSetLauncher'
  c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'SGEControllerLauncher'
  c.SlurmEngineSetLauncher.batch_template_file = '/home/USERNAME/.ipython/profile_sge/sge.engine.template'
  c.SlurmControllerLauncher.batch_template_file = '/home/USERNAME/.ipython/profile_sge/sge.controller.template'
  ```
- `ipcontroller_config.py`:

  ```
  c.HubFactory.ip = '*'
  ```
- `sge.controller.template`

  ```
  # /bin/sh
  #$ -S /bin/sh
  #$ -pe orte 1
  #$ -q sThC.q
  #$ -cwd
  #$ -N ipyparallel_controller
  #$ -o ipyparallel_controller.log
  #$ -e ipyparallel_controller.err
  module load gcc/5.3/openmpi 
  source activate parallel
  ipcontroller --profile-dir={profile_dir}
  ```
- `sge.engine.template`

  ```
  # /bin/sh
  #$ -S /bin/sh
  #$ -pe orte {n}
  #$ -q sThC.q
  #$ -cwd
  #$ -N ipyparallel_engines
  #$ -o ipyparallel_engines.log
  #$ -e ipyparallel_engines.err

  module load gcc/5.3/openmpi
  source activate parallel
  mpiexec -n {n} ipengine --profile-dir={profile_dir} --timeout=30
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution/bug myself:

in `ipcluster_config.py`, I forgot to rename some cases of `Slurm`->`SGE`, so it should be

```py
c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SGEEngineSetLauncher'
c.IPClusterStart.controller_launcher_class = 'SGEControllerLauncher'
c.SGEEngineSetLauncher.batch_template_file = '/home/USERNAME/.ipython/profile_sge/sge.engine.template'
c.SGEControllerLauncher.batch_template_file = '/home/USERNAME/.ipython/profile_sge/sge.controller.template'
```

This lead `ipcluster` to use some kind of default SGE template, that submitted 100 separate jobs instead of one job with 100 processes.

Now I get as desired:

```
[stdout:0] I am #5 of 100 and run on compute-5-17.local
[stdout:1] I am #9 of 100 and run on compute-5-17.local
[stdout:2] I am #1 of 100 and run on compute-5-17.local
[stdout:3] I am #7 of 100 and run on compute-5-17.local
[stdout:4] I am #2 of 100 and run on compute-5-17.local
...
```